# AttributeError: 'selenium' object has no attribute 'send_keys' with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

I created my selenium IDE test, I exported the test to Python 2 Remote control. When I run the script it gives me this error:

```
[root@localhost python]# ./check_selenium.py -s pruebas -w 40 -c 60
SELENIUM UNKNOWN FAIL: not all tests passed -> pruebas  | E
======================================================================
ERROR: test (__main__.test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pruebas", line 21, in
    sel.send_keys("id=buscador", "3")
AttributeError: 'selenium' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 59.428s
```

Can not use keys with Remote control?

this is my line:

```
 sel.send_keys("id=buscador", "3")
```

Regards

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Do you have a minimal, complete, and verifiable example? I have no idea how you defined the sel variable.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Selenium docs, [`send_keys`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=send_keys#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.send_keys) does not prive that kind of call. I think, you need to find the element object with `find_element_by_id`, first. Then call `send_keys` of that object.

```
sel.find_element_by_id("buscadorReferencia_widget").send_keys("8090393")
```

(This assumes, that `sel` is your web driver object.)